# How to speed up string construction from characters in a doubly-nested list?

Tags: python

A common speedup for string concatenations is changing something like

```
s = ""
for x in list:
    s += some_function(x)
```

to

```
slist = [some_function(elt) for elt in somelist]
s = "".join(slist)
```

However, how could this apply if your 'for' was doubly nested? For example...

```
s = ""
for x in list:
    for y in x:
        s += some_function(y)
```

Comment: Tangental: note that specifically in newer versions of CPython, appending to a string is actually very fast and using an array join is no longer a major improvement.  (Due to GC issues, this doesn't translate to Jython.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
''.join(func(c) for s in somelist for c in s)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string_list = []
for x in list:
    for y in x:
        string_list.append(some_function(y))

the_string = ''.join(string_list)
```